# If Bind Values equals to Null change the bind value

Tags: php, pdo

How I can achieve if the `$_POST['sector']` is NULL , the bind value to be changed to 1

```
$stmt->bindValue(':sector', $_POST['sector'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this ternary condition, but you might want to use `isset` instead:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':sector', !is_null($_POST['sector']) ? $_POST['sector'] : "anotherValue", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Maybe you also want to add, that in PHP 7 you will be able to use the `??` [null-coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)